# Facebook connect And Yahoo.. How and what exactly happened? Is there way to import facebook friend's email id?

Tags: facebook

I have seen that yahoo now enables their users to import facebook friend's email addresses into their yahoo addressbook. As far as i know, facebook doesn't allow any API to fetch email addresses of any user on external websites. I have also seen that Yahoo imports email addresses only when the friend's have chosen not to display their contact email to themselves only. Many people in the world trying to implement applications using facebook's API to import email addresses of friend's (Only those email addresses which are visible on user's facebook profile) but API calls always return NULL to their requests. So i would like to know what exactly happened between facebook and yahoo? Does facebook have provided any concessions to Yahoo's addressbook importer application to import facebook user's email addresses? Is there any working API/method/way available to fetch email addresses of facebook friends who have chosen to display their contact email ids on their profile with 1: only visible to friends, 2: visible to everyone privacy settings? I have also seen that, facebook API page clearly listen that email/contact_email field's can be fetched using FQL. Nevertheless there is no official explanation on this issue of returning NULL when email/contact_email is requested from any API call.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook does not provide a way to export email addresses. There has been a [war between gmail and facebook](http://techcrunch.com/2010/11/04/facebook-google-contacts/) the past few months on this topic.

Facebook has tieups with specific websites, and allows only those websites to export emails. You can read the [official note from facebook](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=470023970344).

Essentially, facebook favours certain websites and not others. Their stance is "your friends email address does not belong to you, so we won't let you export".

Comment: aww that sucks!